# How to stick bars to the bottom in this chart

Tags: html, css

I made a chart with html+css (i really need it to work in all browsers)

its ok but the bars are on the top and i need them to stick to the bottom

i tried vertical-align and tried some other things but neither of them worked

Here is a jsfiddle (if you see it you'll know what i mean)

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QzHzT/)

Code:

***CSS:***

```
.clear {clear:both; line-height: 0; width: 0; height: 0}
#chart {
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 17px;
    color: #777777;
}
#scale, #chartwrap, #description {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
#scale {
    margin-top: -7px;
}
#scale i {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}
#chartbox {
    height: 170px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #C7C7C7;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 0;
}
.thisday {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 0 18px;
    width: 40px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.vbottom {
    display: block;
}
.thisday .in, .thisday .out {
    width: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.thisday .in span, .thisday .out span {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #2F6D91;
    display: block;
}
div.inbar, div.outbar {
    width: 18px;
    float: left;
    background: #41799F;
}
div.outbar {
    background: #A5D2F0;
}
div#days {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
div#days i {
    font-size: 11px;
    float: left;
    width: 36px;
    margin: 0 18px;
}
#description {
    margin-left: 7px;
}
#outdes {
    margin-top: 1px;
}
#indes i, #outdes i {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: #40779D;
}
#outdes i {
    background: #A5D2F0;
}
#indes span, #outdes span {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3px;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<div id="chart">
    <div id="scale">
        <i>500</i>
        <i>450</i>
        <i>400</i>
        <i>350</i>
        <i>300</i>
        <i>250</i>
        <i>200</i>
        <i>150</i>
        <i>100</i>
        <i>50</i>
        <i>0</i>
    </div>
    <div id="chartwrap">
        <div id="chartbox">
            <!-- DAILY -->
            <div class="thisday">
                <div class="vbottom">
                    <div class="in">
                        <span>50</span>
                        <div class="inbar" style="height:20px;"></div>
                    </div><div class="out">
                        <span>10</span>
                        <div class="outbar" style="height:5px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /DAILY -->
            <!-- DAILY -->
            <div class="thisday">
                <div class="vbottom">
                    <div class="in">
                        <span>50</span>
                        <div class="inbar" style="height:20px;"></div>
                    </div><div class="out">
                        <span>10</span>
                        <div class="outbar" style="height:5px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /DAILY -->
        <br class="clear">
        </div>
        <div id="days">
            <i>02-17</i>
            <i>02-18</i>
        <br class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="description">
        <div id="indes"><i></i><span>Received</span><br class="clear"></div>
        <div id="outdes"><i></i><span>Sent</span><br class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <br class="clear">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your new CSS code :

```
.clear {clear:both; line-height: 0; width: 0; height: 0}


#chart {
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 17px;
    color: #777777;
}
#scale, #chartwrap, #description {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
#scale {
    margin-top: -7px;
}
#scale i {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}
#chartbox {
    height: 170px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #C7C7C7;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 0;
}
.thisday {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 0 18px;
    width: 40px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
}
.vbottom {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
.thisday .in, .thisday .out {
    width: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.thisday .in span, .thisday .out span {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #2F6D91;
    display: block;
}
div.inbar, div.outbar {
    width: 18px;
    float: left;
    background: #41799F;
}
div.outbar {
    background: #A5D2F0;
}
div#days {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
div#days i {
    font-size: 11px;
    float: left;
    width: 36px;
    margin: 0 18px;
}
#description {
    margin-left: 7px;
}
#outdes {
    margin-top: 1px;
}
#indes i, #outdes i {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: #40779D;
}
#outdes i {
    background: #A5D2F0;
}
#indes span, #outdes span {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3px;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

To sum up, I just added `position: relative;` to the end of `.thisday`, and I also added `position: absolute;` and then `bottom:0px;` to `.vbottom`.

Also, this method will still work if one day you enlarge your graphic. It will stick to the bottom of your graph and you will not have to reajust from top. If you want the bars to go a pixel more or less from the bottom, just do `bottom:-1px;` or `bottom:1px;` instead of 0px and it will be readjusted !

Answer (score 1):

This will make the bars always align along the bottom of the chart. It's a nice solution as long as you don't need to support earlier versions of IE than 8.

```
.thisday {
    display: inline-table;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 0 18px;
    width: 40px;
}
.vbottom {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom
}
```

`.thisday` is the container and has been given `display: inline-table`, and the area supposed to be in the bottom has `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: bottom`.

**EDIT:** since `.vbottom` is not absolutely positioned, `width` on `.thisday` can be left out altogether, in case you might want to add more bars per day or so. That's one clear advantage of this method.

Forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7VvZA/1/

Comment: thank you nicklas, but as i know table-cell is not supported in IE 7 and below

Comment: Ah, then this is not the way to go in your case. But it's a solid option otherwise! I've added a sentence about IE support in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add position relative for **chartbox** class:

```
position: relative;
```

and position absolute for **vbottom** class:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

**UPDATE** (I work in devtools and don't save changes here is updated version):
http://jsfiddle.net/QzHzT/2/

Comment: thanks but the fiddle have the same problem as mine, i think you meant to add position:relative to .thisday (not chartbox)

Comment: no, the update is ok thank you so there is no difference either to add position:relative to #chartbox or .thisday, i up-voted but someone down-voted before me